# Не могу найти getChat в TeleBot (PyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

У меня есть айди чата но никак не могу понять как из него получить [Chat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat)

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

def addTimer():
    chat = bot.getChat("976363234")
    username = chat.username
    
    chat.send_message(chat.id, f'sus')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def addTimer(message):
    chat = bot.get_chat('-10080')
    print(f'{chat.id}\n{chat.type}\n{chat.title}\n{chat.username}\n{chat.first_name}\n{chat.last_name}\n{chat.photo}\n'
          f'{chat.bio}\n{chat.description}\n{chat.invite_link}\n{chat.pinned_message}\n{chat.permissions}\n'
          f'{chat.slow_mode_delay}\n{chat.message_auto_delete_time}\n{chat.sticker_set_name}\n{chat.can_set_sticker_set}'
          f'\n{chat.linked_chat_id}\n{chat.location}')
```

- функция `addTimer` должна принимать один аргумент:

> TypeError: addTimer() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

- метода `getChat` нет:

> AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'getChat'

- у объекта `chat` нет метода `send_message`:

  AttributeError: 'Chat' object has no attribute 'send_message'

[telegram-bot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:234134%20%5Btelegram-bot%5D)
[pytelegrambotapi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:234134%20%5Bpytelegrambotapi%5D)
[telegram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:234134%20%5Btelegram%5D)
[telebot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:234134%20%5Btelebot%5D)

Comment: Я не очень понимаю зачем вы из обычной функции сделали команду, но это пропустим. В целом спасибо

Comment: Чтобы вызвать ее в своем коде, для проверки решения на ваш вопрос, максимально быстро и удобно. Если ответ является решением вашего вопроса, пожалуйста отметьте его таковым, это поможет другим участникам.